# How does "unless" work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to refactor:

```
def play_as_dealer
  if value < 16
      hit!(deck)
      play_as_dealer
   end
end
```

to this version

```
def play_as_dealer
  hit!(deck) unless value > 16
  play_as_dealer
end
```

My version with the **unless** statement does not work. Why is that?

Comment: Do you intend to cause different behavior for `value == 16`, and do you intend to call `play_as_dealer` unconditionally? (That is, to recurse until you run out of stack?)

Comment: Also, the logical opposite of `value < 16` is `value >= 16`. This is not what you have.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the current version, it's easier to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The semantics of `command unless condition` are equivalent to `command if !condition`. The command will be executed if and only if condition is logically false, as opposed to an `if` expression, in which the command will be executed iff the condition is true.

You example can be translated using *unless* like so:

```
def play_as_dealer
  unless value >= 16
    hit!(deck)
    play_as_dealer
  end
end
```

In your example you are using the inline version of the expression, in which the `unless` restriction only has effect on the preceding expression in that line. If you need to restrict two or more commands, use the form in my above example.

Answer (score 2):

I would question why you want to refactor with Unless if your if is working...

However, your **unless** syntax is incorrect in this instance - it is much the same as an if-else-end.

```
def play_as_dealer
  unless value >= 16
    hit!(deck)
    play_as_dealer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the condition after the block, use this:

```
def play_as_dealer
  begin
    hit!(deck) 
    play_as_dealer 
  end unless value >= 16
end
```